# How to create an event on a Graphics2D object in java

Tags: java, image, awt, mouseevent, graphics2d

Please do you know how to add a custom mouse event to a graphics2D object ?

```
image = ImageIO.read(map_file);
logo_maps = ImageIO.read(map_file_logo);
Graphics2D test;
test = image.createGraphics();

test.setColor(Color.red);
test.drawImage(logo_maps,l.getX(),l.getY(), 20, 20,this);
test.drawString(l.getLibelle(), l.getX(),l.getY());
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at that: [The java tutorials: Supporting User Interaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/user.html)